# TeXstudio does not suggest a defined environment when typing

Tags: beamer, texstudio, auto-completion

I do not know why TeXstudio no longer picks up the following environment. Normally, when I type `\begin{in`, TeXstudio will suggest the correct environment `\begin{inlineexample}`. It was working correctly before. Please help.

---

```
\newenvironment{inlineexample}
{\par\vskip\medskipamount
    \refstepcounter{theorem}%
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{block title example}\translate{Example}~\theexample}:}
{\par\vskip\smallskipamount}
```

[image]

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem with such little information. For me works fine with `TeXstudio 2.12.16` . Please check your `TeXstudio` configuration: Options/Configure TexStudio/Completion and provide more details so that others can help you.

Comment: I am also using TeXstudio 2.12.16. At first, it works perfectly and for some reason, it stopped. I posted the completion in the configuration. Only the tex.cwl is check. If there is some other configuration you need, please let me know.

Comment: It works perfectly for me. please uninstall your TexStudio, and restart your machine and go to this path `%APPDATA%\texstudio` and delete textstudio folder. then reinstall it. I hope it works as well as before.

Comment: I am using Window 10 64 bit. The strange thing is it was working and then it stopped.

Comment: Thanks, @C.F.G. Tried your suggestion but it still does not work.

Comment: @hochoi, Try this one: make a notepad text with name `myauto.clw` and content `\begin{inlineexample} \end{inlineexample}` and save it as `.clw` file in this path: `%APPDATA%\texstudio\completion\autogenerated` and then find its name in above image in your post. I hope it works. if everything was OK, then delete this file.

Comment: found the answer! I simply deleted this new environment, saved the file, then added it back and now it is there again. Woo hoo!

Comment: Closed because it has been answered and that was the solution, though the answerer chose to do it via a comment. Can be re-opened if the answerer would like to change that comment into an answer.